# Flexdashboard chart space height auto adjustment

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

Is it possible somehow to make chart space height reactive to number of selections from dropdownlist?
**input$selector2** is a dropdownlist selection vector where you can select multiple names. Each name represents single time-series chart which is plotted in single column with ggplot2::facet_wrap()

below code:

````
```{r} 
len = reactive(as.character(length(unique(input$selector2))*50)) 
len2 = len 
```
       
## Column 

### Row {data-height="`r len2`"}
````

returns:

[image]

without any change in area

Comment: Drop the quotes. ```### Row {data-height=`r len2`}```

Comment: tried that already :( not working 
returns:
Row {data-height=200}

Comment: What options do you have in your YAML?

Comment: ---
title: "title" 

output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
      storyboard: true
  #    navbar: 
  #       - {title: "About", href: "https://google.com"}
      theme: 
          primary: "#16266e"
          base_font: !expr bslib::font_google("Prompt")
          code_font: !expr bslib::font_google("JetBrains Mono")
      orientation: rows
      vertical_layout: scroll
      horizontal_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

Comment: You have the pound symbol (#) in there, what is that supposed to represent? Is this a storyboard with shiny runtime? In a storyboard `###` is a storyboard, so listing it as a row doesn't add up.  Perhaps it would be better if you edited your question and added you YAML.